# Average interest rate vs compound interest rate

Tags: calculation, interest

[image]

(1) Taking an average of %profit

(2) Is calculating %profit by (end-start/start)*100

(3) Is (2) divided by 10 periods

My questions are;

1. What is the REASON why (1) and (3) are different values?
2. What would the compound interest figure be for periods 1 through to 10?

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: Not homework. Just a curiosity!

Comment: (1) and (3) are not equal because of the laws of arithmetic. In general, a/b + c/d does not equal (a+c)/(b+d).

Answer (score 2):

**(2)** is the cumulative rate of return.  It is the final period's end of period value divided by the initial period's start of period value:

```
100% ( final / initial - 1 )
```

**(3)** is the arithmetic mean of the total return, which is very non-standard:

```
cumulative rate of return / number of time periods
```

**(1)** is the arithmetic mean of the period profit percentages which is a simple average:

```
SUM( periodic profit percentage ) / number of periods
```

**NOTE:** For such low rates, the geometric and arithmetic means will be almost identical, as [discovered by Irving Fisher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_equation).

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you one simple example -

- year 1 +10%
- year 2 -10%

The average is 0% return, breakeven, right? But 1.1 * .9 = .99. If $100 gains 10% you end year one with $110, but lose 10% and you have $99.